# Java and design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, nullable

In my subclass I add  object or entity .  And when i debug is my  clazz is null .
I don't understand that can guys  tell my why . Thank you.

```
public abstract class BaseDao<Clazz> implements BaseDaoInteface {
private Session session;
private Class<Clazz> clazz;

public List<Clazz> selectAll() {
    ;
    this.session = Hibernate.getConnection();
    List<Clazz> list = this.session
            .createQuery("select e from " + this.clazz.getName() + "status = " + Constant.Status.ACTIVE, this.clazz)
            .getResultList();
    Utility.closeSession(session);
    return list;
}}


public class DirectoryDao extends BaseDao<Directory>{
public  DirectoryDao() {
    super();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DirectoryDao dao = new DirectoryDao();
    List<Directory> list = dao.selectAll();
//  dao.selectAll();
//  dao.insertOne(new String[] {"a "}, new String[] {"a "});
    list.forEach((ele) ->{
        System.out.println(ele.getUsername());
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please copy and  paste the code into your question, I don't have bandwidth for images!

Comment: I don't see you setting the field "clazz" anywhere, could you state the line where you initialize it? If you don't, it will of course always be null.

Answer (score 0):

This works now

```
public  class BaseDao<Clazz> implements BaseDaoInteface {
private Session session;
private final Class<Clazz> clazz;

public BaseDao(Class<Clazz> entity) {
    this.clazz = entity;
}
```

I add  construct in my abstract class